# Create Html.ActionLink without caption encoding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create a link with caption "next + →". Is there any way to create Html.ActionLink without caption encoding?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You mean setting the "title" attribute?

Comment: Yes, I mean anchor title attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this issue and didn't find an easy way around it.  Sadly the title parameter is a simple `System.String` instead of an `MvcHtmlString`.

When my team needed unencoded titles, we just fell back to anchor tags.

```
<a href="Url.Action(/* etc. */)">raw html</a>
```

Comment: Another option I see is to create ActionLink extension method that retrieves HtmlString as title